# Outlets working intermittently after changing one switch

Tags: electrical

I recently changed one light switch with a new Wemo WIFI switch.
I'm not sure what i did but probably because the switch was in a 2 gang with another switch for a sconce it caused some mixed up.

The bottom line problem is that now, a couple of receptacles that seem on the same line and breaker don't work properly, they don't output power, they actually read sometime 30v sometimes 70v not 120v.

The other day I woke up and I saw one outlet was working (I left a small tester with 3 led lights inserted), so I was excited and I close all the wall plates thinking that the problem was fixed.

Today I noticed again those outlets don't work.

Before paying an electrician, since I'm the owner and I have all the best equipment and some knowledge (but not enough I guess) I'd like to troubleshoot it. What can it be?

The strange thing to me is this intermittency - power comes back but then goes away.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box you worked in?

Comment: Probably a loose wire in one of the switches or outlets along the line. Particularly a stab in connector.

Answer (score 3):

Electric can be finicky, you may be geting a low reading because of a bad or loose ground or neutral, I would suggest opening up the swichbox and recheck all connections inside even if you haven't just previously changed or moved them.

Answer (score 2):

Reopen the box(es) in which you did *your* work, and double check that:

- All wire nuts are tight

  - Hold the nut, pull *hard* on each individual wire - none should move
- Make sure that all wires are securely fastened under their screws and that the screws are down to the proper torque.

  - You don't have a torque screwdriver? Make sure they're *tight*, then a little tighter.
- If you're using any "push-to-insert" connectors in the backs of *any* of the devices (commonly referred to as "backstabs"). Don't.

  - Pull the wires out of the backstabs
  - Bundle them together with wire nuts as appropriate, adding an extra piece of wire called a "pig-tail"
  - Bend a proper shepherd's hook in the end of the wire
  - Attach it under the screw terminal on the device
  - Yes, this takes longer than using a backstab, but the tiny piece of metal that acts as spring & clamp in the backstab hole can (and will) weaken over time leading to a poor, intermittent connection that can cause heating, arcing and start fires. This is especially common in receptacles where you insert/remove plugs and the physical stress causes the receptacle to move against the wire, accelerating the wear.

Since you have an intermittent connection, it's highly likely that a weakened backstab is the culprit. Be thankful that your warning was power issues, not a fire.

If you find that backstabs were used in these devices, it would be worth your time to spend an hour or two each weekend (or tackle them all at once) checking *all* the other outlets & switches in your house for backstab connections. Simply rewire them properly (as noted above), to eliminate potential issues in the future.